# Strange bug, search results not showing

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I'm on my mobile, and suddenly, I see no search results on MetaSE for my searches. I typed the word "meta" in search and got this:

> [image: Search results for *meta*: Your search returned no matches]

The url for that page is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Meta`

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Searching for meta on meta leads to an infinite loop. This is by design....

Comment: @rene I searched "moderator" and got the same result.

Comment: Oh ... then it is a bug ... or it is still looping on your previous search ...

Comment: I saw this too, but it seems to be functioning again now

Comment: @rene Furthermore, searching "meta" after clicking full site gives me a result.

Comment: @TaylorScott Ahh now it's working. I wonder what happened.

Comment: @Unitato it was probably some form of site maintainence

Comment: @rene that's a joke right?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I would spoil the fun when I admit it was ...

Comment: @rene yeah of course I know what happens if you search for "recursion" on google ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it may be a server maintenance, as I got the searches back working on now.

[image]

The url is still the same, however: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Meta`